# How to use Redactor image upload in laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, redactor

I am trying to use Redactor with Laravel4. I can succesfully  edit my textarea but I cant get to work with image uploads.  When I try to upload a file I get 500 error and In developer tools , I can see

```
Request URL:http://projemiz.dev/admin/blogs/3/postimage/3
```

This is my link for redactor photo upload:

```
<script>$('#editor').redactor({ imageUpload: "postimage/{{$post->id}}"});</script>
```

My routes are inside prefixes :

```
# Blog Management
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'blogs'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'blogs', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Admin\BlogsController@getIndex'));
    Route::get('create', array('as' => 'create/blog', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Admin\BlogsController@getCreate'));
    Route::post('create', 'Controllers\Admin\BlogsController@postCreate');
    Route::get('{blogId}/edit', array('as' => 'update/blog', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Admin\BlogsController@getEdit'));
    Route::post('{blogId}/edit', 'Controllers\Admin\BlogsController@postEdit');
    Route::post('{blogId}/postimage','Controllers\Admin\BlogsController@postImage');
    Route::get('{blogId}/delete', array('as' => 'delete/blog', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Admin\BlogsController@getDelete'));
});
```

and my controller is :

```
public function postImage($blogId) {

    $path = base_path().'/public/uploads/img/posts/' . (int)$blogId;

    $image = Input::file('photo');

    if (Input::hasFile('photo'))
    {
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $image->move($path,$fileName);
        $image = new Image;
        $image->name = $fileName.name;
        $image->save();
        // resizing an uploaded file


        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(300, 200)->save($path.'thumb-'.$fileName);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(300, 200)->save($path.'thumb-'.$fileName);


        //File::delete( $path . '/' . Input::file('file.name'));*/
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me to fix my link inside redactor?

Comment: What does your webserver log says to you?

Comment: In access_logs I can find 127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2013:17:08:19 +0300] "POST /admin/blogs/3/postimage/3 HTTP/1.1" 500 37974
... no error inside error_logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your js-script this:

```
<script>$('#editor').redactor({ imageUpload: "/{{$post->id}}/postimage"});</script>
```

In the upload function return the path of the image after upload

```
public function postImage($blogId) 
{

    $path = base_path().'/public/uploads/img/posts/' . (int)$blogId;

    $image = Input::file('photo');

    if (Input::hasFile('photo'))
    {
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $image->move($path,$fileName);
        $image = new Image;
        $image->name = $fileName.name;
        $image->save();

        // resizing an uploaded file
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(300, 200)->save($path.'thumb-'.$fileName);
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(300, 200)->save($path.'thumb-'.$fileName);

        // Return Image path as JSON
       if ($file->move($path, $fileName))
       {
           return Response::json(array('filelink' => $path . '/' . $fileName));
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your controller. but link does not send me correct address

Comment: the above code snippet is a function not a controller. Are you saying the Json Response or the Redactor imageUpload url is broken? What is the error?

Comment: this is one of my controller actions , I have just forgotten to write it. I guess redactor imageupload has a problem. still trying to solve it.